# Solr : Inconsistent search results

Tags: java, solr, solrj, lucene

I am experiencing inconsistent search result for a particular keyword in Solr.

Behavior:

For e.g. Keyword is 'music' and have 3 document indexed containing this keyword.

Perform search with this keyword using URL "http://abc.xyz.com:8983/solr/core3/select/?q=music", It will give single document when we hit it again it will return all three indexed document. Again we hit it will return single document. This is how inconsistent behavior occurring consistently.

I am not able to think of what is causing the issue.

Is it Solr cache? Has it something to do with with other Solr configuration?

Solr Version : 3.6.1

Important Configuration from solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <int name="rows">50</int>
        <str name="df">keywords</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">db-data-config-xsl.xml</str>
    </lst>  
</requestHandler>

<filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0"/>
<queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0"/>
```

schema.xml

```
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="shingleString" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

            <filter class="solr.PositionFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="facet_tex" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer>

            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>   
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />        
            <!--filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"  pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"   /-->
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="facet_comma" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=","/>

            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />   
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>             
            <!--filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"  pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"   /-->
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

        <fieldType name="text_auto" class="solr.TextField">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=","/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />  
                <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" side="front" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>


    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />

            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="," replacement=" "/>

            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="," replacement=" "/>

            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_en_comma" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">

            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="," replacement=" "/>

            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />

            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>

        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">

            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"                />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>

        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>

            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />

            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />

            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_en_suggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=","/>
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=","/>
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
</types>

<fields>   

    <field name="section"     type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="url"    type="string"    indexed="false"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="title"    type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="description"     type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="keywords"     type="text_en_comma"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true" /> 
    <field name="category"    type="facet_comma"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />  
    <field name="robots"    type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />  
    <field name="keywords_suggest"     type="text_en_suggest"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true" /> 

</fields>

<copyField source="keywords" dest="keywords_suggest"/>



<uniqueKey>title</uniqueKey>


<defaultSearchField>keywords</defaultSearchField>


<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

Would appreciate if someone can guide.

Thanks,
Bhavesh

Comment: A few questions: 1) Are you having the core(core3) setup as a stub for distributed querying? 2) Is an indexing job running in the background? You can try using the solr admin panel to give you a detailed analysis of how the documents matched the query. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdminGUI

Comment: I had multiple core set up but not for distributed querying just for backup. I am not sure how to partition indexes between cores. Answer to your first question consider there is only one core and it is named core3. For second question, I perform indexing manually by hitting https://abc.xyz.com/solr/core3/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true. Which part should I focus from analysis for this particular issue?

Comment: 1) Focus on the admin panel query analysis... 2) You can also open the indexed files within corename\data\index *.fdt file and see if your keyword is present. This index file will not be human readable and this kind of analysis is not fool proof but for simple documents you can see if the keyword is repeated thrice in that index.. Also, can you explain how you are using the cores for backup?

Comment: Before doing anything else, I would check if you are getting those results when using command line tools. Perhaps you are having browser-cache issues. Especially if you are comparing two browsers/machines side-by-side. Command line tools skip all the browser machinery and just give you row query results. That's a good half-way point. Or, run developer tools in a browser and watch network panel for cached responses.

Comment: +1 for the above suggestion of cached browser responses. Also, you can look at the servlet container(Tomcat or Jetty) logs as there will be useful debug info logged by solr when hosted as WAR. You can use also the query param debugQuery=true in the url as a shortcut for admin panel analysis

Comment: AlexandreRafalovitch : Good Point. Can you please suggest me command line tool you are referring to? Thank You.

Comment: curl -v "http://abc.xyz.com:8983/solr/core3/select/?q=music"

Answer (score 0):

Check your param [timeAllowed](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#timeAllowed) , It can be describe in some handler in solrconfix.xml

Also questions: how big your index is ? how mush docs, wil be greate to look on your solrconfix.xml and scheme.xml files.

Comment: Index is pretty small, merely 40 documents. I am using Solr 3.6.1 version. solrconfig.xml is quite a huge document, however important please have a look at important configuration above.

Comment: can you share your scheme.xml (just fields block and some types if you use custom types) ?

Comment: Is it possible to share a file or I have to paste whole stuff in here??

Comment: I have updated question with schema.xml, Don't know why its not able to accommodate everything I pasted over there. Hope you will get the idea at least.

Comment: I can't view your config from link, such as you do not share it, But as I see on part of config — it should work..

Comment: I don't know but somehow its started working without a penny of change. Only thing I did was rebuilt the indexes with clean=true